# How to import 2 images in same Product using magmi - Excel Format?

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

How to import `multiple images` of same products by using **magmi?**

My format is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Extra product images are handled through **`media_gallery`** column.

Since several images can be set in this column,a specific syntax has been set to handle labels.

- The Extended syntax with :: for setting labels ONLY APPLIES TO media_gallery column
- TO SET BASE IMAGE LABELS USE BASE IMAGE LABEL RELATED COLUMNS.

For more details, please have a look at below links:

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor#Example_.28with_no_labels.29:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13319/magmi-import-extra-images-how (Answer by @Malcolm Dezign)

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: @ Mohit Kumar Arora, @ Termininja : is it possible import images via Magmi by using images from other server,  actually I need to import images from other server using magmi, actually my products in server 1, but my all images present at server 2 how can i import server 2 images for my server 1 products, how can i do it.

Comment: Hi @JeevaRathinam, please have a look at answer in this thread:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107588/how-can-i-import-product-image-from-an-external-url-in-magento-1-9